# XSL transformation failed to compile stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to get the playlists saved in a iTunes library using XSLT. I'm following [this article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/11/03/itunes.html) and am using the first XML on the second page as scheme for the transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:variable name="newline">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/key[text()='Playlists']/ \
following-sibling::array/dict">
      <xsl:value-of select="key[text()='Name']/ \
following-sibling::string" /><xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Java code looks like this:

```
private File library = new File("iTunes Music Library.xml");

public String getPlaylists() {
        Source source = new StreamSource(library);
        StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("iTunesPL.xml")); //the XSL above
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(w);
        try {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            return w.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But it isn't working. The error displayed is the following: (Translated into English by me, so might not look exactly the same on your systems...)

```
[Fatal Error] :2:6: Procession-command-target corresponding to "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
ERROR:  'Stylesheet couldn't be compiled.'
FATAL ERROR:  "Stylesheet konnte nicht kompiliert werden"
           :Procession-command-target corresponding to "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Stylesheet couldn't be compiled
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:891)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:671)
    at me.the_seppi.jaisb.ITunesPlaylistFetcher.convert(ITunesPlaylistFetcher.java:27)
    at me.the_seppi.jaisb.Main.getITunesPlaylists(Main.java:193)
    at me.the_seppi.jaisb.Main.main(Main.java:40)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; Procession-command-target corresponding to "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:427)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:479)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:354)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:456)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:852)
    ... 6 more
---------
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; Procession-command-target corresponding to "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:427)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:479)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:354)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:456)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:671)
    at me.the_seppi.jaisb.ITunesPlaylistFetcher.convert(ITunesPlaylistFetcher.java:27)
    at me.the_seppi.jaisb.Main.getITunesPlaylists(Main.java:193)
    at me.the_seppi.jaisb.Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

What am I doing wrong? The library was created by iTunes 10.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes are not supposed to be there. Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:variable name="newline">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/key[text()='Playlists']/following-sibling::array/dict">
        <xsl:value-of select="key[text()='Name']/following-sibling::string" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Or just get rid of the backslashes. A newline between the attributes will do no harm. (I presume you thought you had to escape it. You don't.)